# Ошибка в переборе HashMap

Tags: java

Хочу перебрать свою хешмапу, но при написании цикла возникает ошибка

```
Incompatible types. Found: 'java.util.Map.Entry<java.lang.String,java.lang.Integer>', required: 'java.lang.Object'
```

Как можно исправить? Вот весь код:

```
public static void writeToFile(HashMap averageTime) {
        try {
            File file = new File("newfile.txt");
            if (!file.exists())
                file.createNewFile();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file);
            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : averageTime.entrySet()) {
                pw.println("IP: " + entry.getKey() + "AverageTime: " + entry.getValue());
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Хэш-мапа в объявлении метода не типизирована, а внутри метода набор её элементов уже типизирован.

Нужно изменить тип входного аргумента:

- использовать интерфейс `Map`
- задекларировать типы ключей / значений в мапе

```java
public static void writeToFile(Map<String, Integer> averageTime) {
// ...
}
```